# Activity endpoint?

Tags: api, foursquare

Will there be an "activity" endpoint for us 3rd Party developers to use so we may build apps that have the same information as the "official" apps?

Even piecing together data from other endpoints we cannot build such a feature since there's no way for us to get checkin history for users other than "self". We can only get other users last checkin.

Thought I'd read some time ago that the website and official apps were just going to use the api so there must be some hidden/not public endpoints.

Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official app does use the same endpoints exposed through the API, but the public API is only a subset of what the official app uses :) (e.g., we don't allow account creation)

Having said that, there's currently no "activity" endpoint we expose, nor will we likely expose one in the future. Sorry bout that!